# Using a loop to turn several matrices into data frames

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to write a loop that takes multiple 1x2 matrices, adds column names, and turns them into tables.

My matrices look like this:

```
Floor4 <- matrix(c(167, 168, 170, 177,178,179, 180, 335, 336, 343, 344, 353, 489, 490, 498, 501, 502, 45,44,45,45,46,46,44,46,46,44,46,46,45,45,45,45,45), ncol = 2, byrow = F)
```

I concatenated them into a list like this:

```
floor_list <- list(Floor2, Floor3, Floor4)
```

I'd like to write a for loop that attaches column names and then turns the object into a table, something like this:

```
for (i in floor_list) {
  colnames(i) <- c("Flight", "Total")
  i <- as.table(i)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Probably because of the `for()` loop. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Does it need to be a table, as opposed to a data frame?

Comment: I ended up using MonJeanJean's code and using as.data.frame instead. Great advice, I appreciate y'all so much! I was nervous about asking my first question because I've seen how savage some people on here are, but my question was answered within an hour and only one downvote! Success!

Answer (score 0):

I made a few modifications to your code. I use the package `data.table` to get tables. Then I changed the output name for each table:

```
x = 0
for (i in floor_list) {
  colnames(i) <- c("Flight", "Total")
  out <- as.data.table(i)
  assign(paste("Table",x,sep = "_"), out)
  x <- x + 1
}
```

That ain't pretty, but it is working